# Ubuntu terminal ignoring interpreter first line

Tags: command-line, bash

I am Windows user running WSL2 with success over the last two years. I work on a project connected to a git repository. All devs work on mac/linux so all parts of this project are targeted towards those types of systems, including things like pre commit hooks.

Recently I decided to try out Webstorm so I installed it on Windows and it also has a WSL counterpart that it installs to. Everything worked fine until I tried to commit something to the repo, which calls a pre-commit husky hook that looks like this

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env node
const fs = require('fs');
const cp = require('child_process');
const { join } = require('path');

// ... then do some stuff in node/js
```

However since installing Webstorm I now get this error

```
.husky/commit-msg: 2: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
husky - commit-msg script failed (code 2)
```

I've gone down many paths, verified node is installed and symlinked, but it seems from my interpretation that even though I am using a bash terminal to do everything, maybe it's using `sh` instead?

For instance I landed in this [page](https://www.baeldung.com/linux/illegal-option-o-pipefail) because now I also get this error in an unrelated file

`Illegal option -o pipefail`

and that page suggests "use bash instead of sh" which I *am*, but seemingly not.

Any ideas? What can query/test to see if I am using bash and not sh (even though I am in a bash terminal :S )

Comment: I'm not familiar with husky, however I was browsing the [v9.0.1 release notes](https://github.com/typicode/husky/releases/tag/v9.0.1) and noticed the following (under **How to Migrate**) *"Note: sh will be used to run hooks, even if a shebang is set."*

Comment: ... see also [Support arbitrary shells for hook scripts #971](https://github.com/typicode/husky/issues/971)

Comment: This isn't about bash vs sh, you would get the same error in either shell. It's almost certainly what @steeldriver wrote above (might as well post that as an answer, steeldriver).

Comment: @terdon thanks for the reminder - done

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has nothing to do with what *interactive* shell you are using (i.e. bash versus sh<sup>1</sup>) - and in fact nothing to do with Ubuntu or WSL. It appears to be a limitation of the husky hook mechanism itself, as noted in the **How to Migrate** section of the [husky v9.0.1 release notes](https://github.com/typicode/husky/releases/tag/v9.0.1):

> *Note: `sh` will be used to run hooks, even if a shebang is set.*

Supporting other interpreters is the subject of a closed feature request:

- [Support arbitrary shells for hook scripts #971](https://github.com/typicode/husky/issues/971)

So, if you want to run your node script from a hook, you will need to do so from a POSIX sh-compatible wrapper.

---

1. if you ran the same node script in bash, you'd get a similar (albeit slightly more informative) error

   ```
   .husky/commit-msg: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token `('
   .husky/commit-msg: line 2: `const fs = require('fs');'
   ```

Comment: Thanks.. not a very cool thing for that author to do. I wonder how many repos he broke. :S

Answer (score 2):

You can work around the problem with a polyglot file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
// 2>/dev/null ; exec /usr/bin/env node "$0" "$@"
const fs = require('fs');
const cp = require('child_process');
const { join } = require('path');

// ... then do some stuff in node/js
```

The `//` line is ignored by node. In bash, the `//` part errors out but is silenced by the `2>/dev/null`. The part after `;` is run as the next statement, which opens the correct Nodejs interpreter. When that part is parsed by Node, it is still in the comment so it's properly ignored.

Comment: Interesting. We opted to convert the file to a js file and just run it in a different way.

Comment: Clever - I was thinking it would need a separate wrapper script